# Populate drop down <ul> with directory contents

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to write a simple php script that will populate a drop down unordered list with the file contents of a directory. Specifically .wav files. I'm HTML using and Bootstrap to do so.

Here is the list I've been working on:

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <h4 style="color: #333333">Select a Sound -</h4> <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Moose.wav</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Duck.wav</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Goose.wav</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
</ul>

<?php 
          foreach(glob('sounds/*.wav') as $filename){
          $rest = substr($filename, 7);    
          echo "<option>".$rest."</option>";
          }
?>
```

Right now it's populated with hard coded values, Moose, Duck, etc . . . I've been working on this php script, I just don't know how to combine the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<ul>
<?php 
      foreach(glob('sounds/*.wav') as $filename){
      $rest = substr($filename, 7);    
      echo "<li><a href='#'>".$rest."</a></li>";
      }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think that's close. When I click the drop down though all I see is ".$rest."";}?>

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this based on the assumption that all the code you provided are working perfectly as intended.

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <h4 style="color: #333333">Select a Sound -</h4> <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <?php foreach(glob('sounds/*.wav') as $filename){
              $rest = substr($filename, 7);    
              echo "<li>".$rest."</li>";
            }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

The idea is to write a PHP loop to generate your list items. This loop would reside within the  tags, hence making the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basename() to get only the filename, no need for substr()

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <h4 style="color: #333333">Select a Sound -</h4> <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <?php foreach(glob('sounds/*.wav') as $filename):?>
             <li><a href="#"><?php echo basename($filename);?></a></li>
          <?php endforeach;?>
          </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```